# Asus A8N-SLI Premium error

Tags: motherboard

I have an old Asus A8N-SLI Premium motherboard. I turned it off yesterday night and this morning I tried to boot it. It won't boot and it beeps. There's the beeping.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lb0UvZTR2BE

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one of the PCIe slots is not working. I switched the GPU to another slot and now it works.